# I want to check out from a mirror, but commit to the master

Tags: svn

followed this URL "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt" ,synchronising is success full,but  after check-out data from slave server ,i am trying to checking data to master,at that time its asking slaves authentications after successful login to slave its giving error that "svn: 'directory' is not a working copy
 ,can any one give me steps how to check-in to check-in to master server.how to use "svn switch --relocate " command .

Answer (score 4):

First off, the best answer is to setup a WebDAV write-thru proxy on your slave.  This lets you treat the slave as if it was your master and the slave will act as a proxy for the master whenever you perform a write operation.  This lets you get the benefit of the slave for all read operations.  See: [Blog Post on configuring WebDAV proxy](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2007/10/yesterday-at-th/)

To answer your question about how to use switch --relocate, suppose you ran this command:

```
svn co http://slave-server/svn/repos/trunk wc
```

From the working copy, you would run this command:

```
cd wc
svn sw --relocate http://slave-server http://master-server .
```

You only have to change the part of the URL that is varies.  So as long as the rest of the URL is the same, that is all you need to specify.  If they were really different, you might do:

```
svn sw --relocate http://slave-server/svn/repos http://master-server/repos .
```